# How do I get visual studio code to run a programming language that I created?

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-construction, ide, vscode-extensions, interpreter

I'm trying to get the visual studio code IDE to support a programming language that I created using python. I want vscode to have basic language and intellisense support for my language. Also, I would like the program to use the .csap file extension. Less importantly, I am interested in making a debugger extension.

Its a very simple programming language with print statements, loops, input, conditions, and some of my own built-in functions.

It is very similar to python. I have it working in my terminal right now.

What are the most important ideas for me to know about to make these extensions? What are the best resources and tutorials on the subject?

If you believe this post is to broad, please advise me on how to make it more specific.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd have to create plugins to support syntax highlighting, autocomplete, etc. Your "interpreter" would need to point to some sort of executable that runs your language to parse `.csap` files. This question is going to be a bit broad IMO

Comment: I guess you could start reading [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview), although that's mostly about getting the IDE to handle your language (syntax highlighting, tab-completion, autoindent, etc.) If you want VSCode to be able to help you debug programs in your language, you'll need to write a debugger extension, which is quite a lot more work. You could make your question more precise by specifying exactly what you want to be able to do.

Comment: Thanks! for the advice I made some edits, so hopefully that makes it somewhat more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the entire ecosystem for your new language, so I see at least 2, maybe 3 kind of extensions, and could look these resources:

- Syntax Highlight:

  - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide
  - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide
- Intellisense like features:

  - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features
  - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide
- Debugger

  - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension

This repo (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples) contains a lot of samples, and is a great source of information.

Hope this helps